# Get URL variable in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the authentification controller

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('Mql14mqlmeBundle:User');

   if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $username = $request->get('login');
    $password = $request->get('pass');
          if(($username=='admin')&&($password=='admin')){

           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mql14mqlme_admin',  array('name' => 'welcome')));
            }

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('login' => $username, 'pass' =>  $password));

    if ($user) {

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mql14mqlme_acceuil', array('name' => $user->getNom(),
                'id'=> $user->getId(),
            )));


    }else {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mql14mqlme_homepage', array('name' =>$username)));
  }
```

If the user has provided the right login and password he is redirected to acceuil twig, in this twig I want to get the user's id to use it in another twig, so the line where I have a problem is this:

```
<a href="{{ path('mql14mqlme_interet', { 'id': name   }) }}">INTERETS</a>
```

the error I get is:Variable "name" does not exist in Mql14mqlmeBundle:Default:acceuil.html.twig at line 89

The action code for acceuil:

```
public function acceuilAction()
{

$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$evenements= $em->getRepository('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Evenement')->findAll();
$categories= $em->getRepository('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Categorie')->findAll();
return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Default:acceuil.html.twig',
        array(
                'evenements' => $evenements,
                'categories' => $categories
        ));

}
```

Comment: Can you add your PHP code where you render the twig template?

Comment: Could you post the action code for `mql14mqlme_acceuil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
<a href="{{ path('mql14mqlme_interet', { 'id': app.request.get('name') }) }}">INTERETS</a>
```

Question :

Does your

> $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('login' => $username, 'pass' =>  $password));

indicates that your looking for user by plain password ?

Comment: Thank you david your suggestion works perfectly, I'm able to pass the variable into the twig

Answer (score 0):

In twig, all variables need to be passed in when you call render. EG:

`echo $template->render(array('name' => 'bob'));`

Comment: so it's not possible to get a variable that was passed in the URL?

Comment: Not in the template, no. You could probably write your own twig function to pull a get parameter, but that would be far more roundabout than just passing in the var from the controller. Are you not able to modify that controller?

Comment: in the index action instead of redirect I did this :return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Default:acceuil.html.twig',array('user' => $user,
));But I think that it's not possible to render a twig from two different controller if I'm not mistaken

Comment: You have the variable array in that line! Just add name to `array('user' => $user, )` and it should work

Comment: From a twig template you can call a controller :
    {{ render(controller('NsMyBundle:Default:action')) }}
or
    {{ render(controller('NsMyBundle:Default:action', { parameter: value })) }}

Comment: @DavidJacquel Thats new! Is that a symfony feature? I don't see it in the twig docs

Answer (score 0):

What you need is getting the name from the query string and pass the name to the rendered view

```
public function acceuilAction($name) // <-- This is the name you are passing to request
{
    ...
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('Mql14mqlmeBundle:Default:acceuil.html.twig',
    array(
            'name' => $name, // <-- Here you pass the received name to your twig
            'evenements' => $evenements,
            'categories' => $categories
    ));
}
```

Base on [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls) generating URL and passing arguments as array, means you pass the name through the request. If you want to pass as QueryString (not a part of url path) change the generate URL as

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mql14mqlme_acceuil').'?name='.$user->getId());
```

*In this case you need to change routing and controller, too*